# Can prometheus find alert manager dynamically with out restart itself

Tags: prometheus

I run `prometheus` and `alertmanager` on pods in k8s cluster, I want `prometheus` can find `alertmanager`  dynamically, when `alertmanager` pod start it add it to it's config file without restart itself, because if `prometheus` stop it means the pod that host `prometheus` ends, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus locates the alertmanager via the alertmanager config inside the prometheus config file. When deployed on Kubernetes, the alertmanager pod can start on a new node and thus using an IP address is not a reliable way to point prometheus to the alertmanager.

The recommended way in Kubernetes is to create a service for the alertmanager and use the [service DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records) inside the `prometheus.yml` file. That way prometheus will always be able the alertmanager even when the alertmanager pod restarts on a different node.